# I have an Eclipse SWT Spinner widget format problem

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, spinner

I have a Java application which is based on a scrolled composite form. It is implemented on the Eclipse IDE. Each spinner is declared in the same way, an example being:

```java
  Spinner spCh1;
  spCh1 = new Spinner(this, SWT.BORDER);
     spCh1.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
         @Override
         public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {
             //code handling spinner value in here
         }
     });
     spCh1.setToolTipText("Select character position");
     spCh1.setMaximum(20);
     spCh1.setSelection(1);
     spCh1.setBounds(610, 237, 70, 22);
     spCh1.setFont(SWTResourceManager.getFont("Arial", 8, SWT.NORMAL));
```

I'm running Eclipse:
Version: 2020-12 (4.18.0)
Build id: 20201210-1552 Eclipse 2020-21 on Peppermint 10 Linux.

This application worked fine on previous versions of Eclipse (Neon) and Older Linux Peppermint (3), where the spinner(s) had the Up and down arrows,  but now it has +and - buttons arranged horizontally and has a much bigger footprint which the form hasn't enough real-estate to accommodate the several spinner it requires.

I've tried changing fonts, adjusting the bounds lowering the 'Text Limit' but all to no avail. There only seem to be 3 options on Style *Border*, *Wrap* and *Read Only*. I've tried changing each of these to no avail. The widget is imported into the java class with:

```java
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Spinner;
```

The Java build path includes:

```
<storagefolder>/eclipse-installer/plugins      /org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64_3.115.100.v20201202-1103.jar
```

Comment: Note using `setBounds` is not recommended, you should always use Layouts such as `GridLayout` - but that probably isn't going to make a difference here.

Comment: Probably due the switch to GTK 4, Spinner is just using the native GTK spinner - https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/class.SpinButton.html

Comment: Yes, thanks Greg, the culprit is almost certainly GTK-4. The Eclipse Nebula project has some alternatives which I'll have a look at, I suspect I'll end up writing my own version with configurable button positions etc. I'm using an absolute layout so I can put things exactly where I want them. Inelegant I know but I'm a simple soul....